# Proving a sufficient condition for complex differentiability

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

I'm trying to show that given $f=u+iv:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$
  and $z_{0}\in\mathbb{C}$
  if $u,v$
  are differentiable (as functions $\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R})$
  at $z_{0}=\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)$
  and the limit $$\lim\limits _{z\to z_{0}}\mbox{arg}\left(\frac{f(z)-f\left(z_{0}\right)}{z-z_{0}}\right)$$
  exists then $f$
  is complex differentiable at $z_{0}$
 . I've reached a point where it would suffice if I could show that under these conditions I can conclude that the limit $$\lim\limits _{z\to z_{0}}\left|\frac{f\left(z\right)-f\left(z_{0}\right)}{z-z_{0}}\right|$$
  exists. Now we can see that: $$\lim\limits _{z\to z_{0}}\left|\frac{f\left(z\right)-f\left(z_{0}\right)}{z-z_{0}}\right|=\lim_{z\to z_{0}}\sqrt{\frac{\left(u\left(z\right)-u\left(z_{0}\right)\right)^{2}+\left(v\left(z\right)-v\left(z_{0}\right)\right)^{2}}{\left|z-z_{0}\right|^{2}}}=\sqrt{\lim_{z\to z_{0}}\frac{\left(u\left(z\right)-u\left(z_{0}\right)\right)^{2}+\left(v\left(z\right)-v\left(z_{0}\right)\right)^{2}}{\left|z-z_{0}\right|^{2}}}$$
 So it would suffice if I could show that these following limits exist: $$\lim_{z\to z_{0}}\frac{\left(u\left(z\right)-u\left(z_{0}\right)\right)^{2}}{\left|z-z_{0}\right|^{2}}\quad,\quad\lim_{z\to z_{0}}\frac{\left(v\left(z\right)-v\left(z_{0}\right)\right)^{2}}{\left|z-z_{0}\right|^{2}}$$
 I've tried getting to the existence of these limit from the differentiability of u,v
  but without success.

Note: when wirting $u\left(z\right),v\left(z\right)$
  the intention is of course $ u\left(x,y\right),v\left(x,y\right)
 $
  as these are not complex function but functions $\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}$
 . It's also worth noting that the norm on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$
  is exactly the complex modulus so one can rewrite that we need the existence of the following limits: $$\lim_{\left(x,y\right)\to\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)}\frac{\left(u\left(x,y\right)-u\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)\right)^{2}}{\left\Vert \left(x,y\right)-\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)\right\Vert ^{2}}\quad,\quad\lim_{\left(x,y\right)\to\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)}\frac{\left(v\left(x,y\right)-v\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)\right)^{2}}{\left\Vert \left(x,y\right)-\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)\right\Vert ^{2}}$$

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but aren't the two limits you're trying to evaluate just the respective squares of $u'(z_0)$ and $v'(z_0)$?

Comment: There's no meaning to differentiating $u$ and $v$ as functions of $z$ as they are not complex functions but functions $\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}$. I noted on the notation later on, I referred to $u,v$ as functions of $z$ simply for ease of notation but perhaps it just causes confusion.

Comment: Serpahimz, still, why not express $u(x,y)-u(x_0,y_0)$ as $u(x,y)-u(x,y_0)+u(x,y_0)-u(x_0,y_0)$ and work with the (known) existence of the partials?

Comment: I've tried stuff along those lines but always ended up just transforming the initial limit I'm trying to prove the existence of into another limit I have no justification to say it exists.
If you're willing to give it a go and see if you reach a valid result I'd appreciate it. Generally it would suffice to show the existence of the limits without the squaring, i.e the existence of $\lim_{z\to z_{0}}\frac{u\left(z\right)-u\left(z_{0}\right)}{\left|z-z_{0}\right|}$. This is what I tried and failed.

Comment: @Serpahimz : I tried to verify that my counterexample verified the "arg" condition and I had trouble.  If your claim came from a reliable source, it's probably true.  So I was probably wrong.  I deleted my answer.  Thanks for not downvoting it (I don't think mistakes are the best reason for downvoting answers).

Comment: @StefanSmith No problem. If you have any insight towards proving the claim I would of course appreciate it :)

Comment: Serpahinz, exactly my point.  Neither of us wants to deal with the "squaring".  Except tha you've reduced the problem to the _square_ of a limit that we'd like to verify.  I think it can be done, and I'll post an answer if successful.

Comment: Sorry Serpahimz, not having much success here.  I can't figure out how to use the full strength of the condition on the argument function beyond what you've evidently already used (i.e. the fact that the identity $z=|z|e^{i\, arg(z)}$ reduces the problem of existence of $\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$ to that of $\lim_{z\to z_0} \big\vert\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}\big\vert$.)

Comment: @Serpahimz : this is just an observation : I suspect that your condition is not satisfied by any nonconstant function unless you use some multi-valued version of the "arg" function.  For example, $f(z)=z$ doesn't satisfy the condition: take $z_0 = 0$ and $z_n = \exp((\pi + (-1)^n/n)i)/n$.  Then the sequence $(\operatorname{arg}(f(z_n)/z_n))$ has a subsequence converging to $\pi$ and a subsequence converging to $-\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the concepts we are talking about here are translation invariant we may assume $z_0=f(z_0)=0\in{\mathbb C}$. The assumption that $f=u+iv$ is real differentiable at $(0,0)=0\in{\mathbb C}$ implies
$$u(x,y)=u_1 x+u_2 y+o\bigl(|z|\bigr),\quad v(x,y)=v_1 x+v_2 y+o\bigl(|z|\bigr)\qquad (z\to0)$$ 
with real constants $u_1$, $u_2$, $v_1$, $v_2$. Therefore we have
$$f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)=(u_1+iv_1){z+\bar z\over 2}+(u_2+iv_2){z-\bar z\over 2i}+o\bigl(|z|\bigr)\qquad (z\to0)$$
or
$$f(z)=az+b\bar z+o\bigl(|z|\bigr)\qquad (z\to0)$$
with certain coefficients $a$, $b\in{\mathbb C}$.

If $a=b=0$ then $f$ is complex differentiable at $0$ trivially. Otherwise  assume $a\ne0$ and  write
$$f(z)=a\bigl(z+c\bar z\bigr)+o\bigl(|z|\bigr)\qquad (z\to0)\tag{1}$$
with $c:={b\over a}$.

Let $z=re^{i\phi}$ with $r>0$. Then
$${f(z)\over z}=a\bigl(1+ce^{-2i\phi}\bigr)$$
and therefore
$$\arg{f(z)\over z}=\arg(a)+\arg(1+ce^{-2i\phi})\qquad(r>0)\ .$$
It follows that the existence of $\lim_{z\to0}\arg{f(z)\over z}$ necessitates $c=0$. From $(1)$ we then conclude that
$$f(z)=a z+o\bigl(|z|\bigr)\qquad (z\to0)\ ,$$
which means that $f$ is complex differentiable at $0$. The case $a=0$, $b\ne0$ is dealt with similarly; it is incompatible with the existence of $\lim_{z\to0}\arg{f(z)\over z}$.

Comment: Hello Christian, first of all thanks for replying!
There are two things I don't fully understands. One is why is it possible wlog to assume $f\left(z_{0}\right)=z_{0}=0
$ and the second why under those assumptions we obtain $f(z)=az+b\overline{z}+o(|z|)$. I'd greatly appreciate if you could elaborate. Thanks!

Comment: @Serpahimz: See my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot Christian, I greatly appreciate your help.